# How can I check the previous product used by a customer in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I check the previous product used by a customer , where TRANCODE is the field for all the different products used and currently they are using the product MOG in SQL?

heres what i tried an not able to go anywhere from here..

```
SELECT TRANCODE
FROM PRODUCT_TXN
WHERE TRANSBDATE BETWEEN '01-SEP-2018' AND '31-AUG-2019' AND TRANSSTATUS ='S' AND WHERE CUSTOMERID IN
(SELECT * FROM PRD_TRANSACTIONS
WHERE TRANSBDATE BETWEEN '01-AUG-2019' AND '31-AUG-2019' AND TRANSSTATUS ='S'_)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clearer explanation of what you want to do.

Comment: Not more than one `WHERE` per `SELECT`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT TRANCODE
FROM PRODUCT_TXN
WHERE TRANSBDATE BETWEEN '01-SEP-2018' AND '31-AUG-2019' AND TRANSSTATUS ='S' AND CUSTOMERID IN
(SELECT CUSTOMERID FROM PRD_TRANSACTIONS
WHERE TRANSBDATE BETWEEN '01-AUG-2019' AND '31-AUG-2019' AND TRANSSTATUS ='S')
```

Comment: It works but if i need the output like two columns where one shows previous product and other shows current product?                                                                                                                                                Prev.prod    Customer id                                                                                                      for august they are using MOG and prev.prod coloumns shows what they had before recently